# OCaml pattern-match syntax error without double semi colon

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I am quite new to OCaml, so apologies if this is a silly question. I have this OCaml file:

```
type tree =
  | Node of int * tree * tree
  | Leaf of int

let t = Node (3, Node (4, Leaf 1, Node (3, Leaf 5, Leaf 2)), Leaf 1)

let rec height t =
  match t with
  | Node (n, t1, t2) -> 1 + max (height t1) (height t2)
  | Leaf n -> 0

let _ = print_string (string_of_int (height t))
```

If I compile the file with `ocamlc -o out my_file.ml`, it compiles and runs as expected. However, if I try to run the file with `ocaml < my_file.ml`, I get a syntax error in the definition of my `height` function.

Placing a double semi colon after my `height` function as such:

```
let rec height t =
  match t with
  | Node (n, t1, t2) -> 1 + max (height t1) (height t2)
  | Leaf n -> 0
;;
```

Fixes the issue.

My questions are:

1. Does OCaml require the double semi colons after a pattern-match only in interactive mode? That seems to be where the issue is coming from.
2. Does `ocamlformat` know this? When I run `ocamlformat` on the file, it automatically places a double semi colon after my `height` function. I was confused as to why it was doing that until I got the syntax error.

Thanks in advance for the info! I've looked for answers to these questions but have been unsuccessful. I did find [this blog](https://baturin.org/docs/ocaml-faq/#the-double-semicolon) which claimed the double semi colon is *never* necessary.

Comment: Minor style note: there's no need to convert an `int` to a `string` and then call `print_string`. Instad, just call `print_int`.  `t |> height |> print_int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to run an OCaml file as a script is like this:

```
$ ocaml myfile.ml
```

If you run without a filename, as you are doing, `ocaml` enters an interactive mode in which it expects a person to be typing input with `;;` indicating times when evaluation should occur. It does treat EOF as a syntax error in this mode since you have some unprocessed input at that point.

If you try the above command (without the `<` redirection) you should see the behavior you expect.

Here are my answers to your questions:

1. OCaml doesn't actually require double semicolons anywhere. They are just a method to tell the interpreter (the REPL, also known as toplevel) that it should evaluate what you have typed most recently. This is one way to allow multi-line input.
2. When I run `ocamlformat` I don't see any double semicolons in the output. I can't reproduce this observation of yours.

Here is what I see for the usual way of running a script:

```
$ ocaml myfile.ml
3$
```

Here is what I see when I run `ocamlformat`:

```
$ ocamlformat --enable-outside-detected-project myfile.ml
type tree = Node of int * tree * tree | Leaf of int

let t = Node (3, Node (4, Leaf 1, Node (3, Leaf 5, Leaf 2)), Leaf 1)

let rec height t =
  match t with
  | Node (n, t1, t2) -> 1 + max (height t1) (height t2)
  | Leaf n -> 0

let _ = print_string (string_of_int (height t))
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! That all makes sense, and I now recognize that it was the EOF causing that syntax error. I am running `ocamlformat` with `profile=janestreet`. I've tested with `profile=default` and it strangely does not add that double semi colon. Seems like a harmless difference in those profiles, I guess!